# Has Google WMT removed the "change of address" tool?

Tags: google-search-console

I went over the side menus in WMT and didn't find the "change of address" tool there. Have Google removed it? If so, is there any other decent way to inform them of any domain change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's still there and hasn't moved, at least for me, and it feels like a strange thing to AB test. Make sure you're in a property and click the gear button in the top right.

Here's a direct link to the tool where you can select any of your added and verified properties:

- https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/change-address

Comment: Indeed, what confused me to think Google removed it was reading an old guide from about 2011 that showed the old link in the side menus. Indeed, it was under the gear-wheel in the top right corner of the screen as you said and not as in the old guide.

Comment: @Benia Ah, that's a *really* old guide! Didn't even think about that and thought you were referring to it being moved along with the Webmaster Tools → Search Console change.

Answer (score 2):

Google Webmaster Tools is now called Google Search Console.

In addition to the name change, they have also re-arranged all he menus.   The change of address tool is now available from the gear icon drop down:

[image]